# Is continuity impossible if a function range is a finite union of closed, bounded, disjoint sets?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

Can there ever exist a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^1$ whose domain is $[a, b]$, but whose range is a finite union of closed, bounded, and disjoint sets? For example, if there is an $f(x)$ defined over $[-1,1]$ such that its range is $[5,10]\cup[15,20]$, can it ever be continuous?

*I* think it is impossible for $f$ to be continuous here. But while I can intuitively grasp that for such a range the function will have to "jump" at some point, I do not know how to concretely justify this (either for a general case, or even for a specific case such as the example above).

Comment: Are you aware of the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is well-known that the image of a connected subspace by a continuous function is a connected subspace.

Comment: @SangchulLee OH! So is the argument as follows for my original example?: The function must take the values 5 and 20 somewhere. Then due to IVT, it must also take all values in [5,20]. However, the range given to us does not allow values in (10,15), hence due to the contrapositive of the IVT, our original function is not continuous. I presume the same argument can be further extended to a general case?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much for the kind welcome and for the answer! I'm trying to self-learn mathematics after a decade of having left it, so I intend to lurk on SX a lot :)

Comment: If you allow infinite unions, you may get an interval (which is of course the union of its one-point subsets). Thus you should say "finite union".

Comment: @PaulFrost Makes sense, have edited the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "range" is ambiguous. Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function):

In mathematics, the range of a function may refer to either of two closely related concepts:

- The codomain of the function
- The image of the function

Given two sets $X$ and $Y$, a binary relation $f$ between $X$ and $Y$ is a (total) function (from $X$ to $Y$) if for every $x$ in $X$ there is exactly one $y$ in $Y$ such that $f$ relates $x$ to $y$. The sets $X$ and $Y$ are called domain and codomain of $f$, respectively. The image of $f$ is then the subset of $Y$ consisting of only those elements $y$ of $Y$ such that there is at least one $x$ in $X$ with $f(x) = y$.

**Terminology**

As the term "range" can have different meanings, it is considered a good practice to define it the first time it is used in a textbook or article. Older books, when they use the word "range", tend to use it to mean what is now called the codomain. More modern books, if they use the word "range" at all, generally use it to mean what is now called the image. To avoid any confusion, a number of modern books don't use the word "range" at all.

Thus the answer to your question is "yes" if *range* is understood as codomain (take any constant function with value in the codomain) and "no" if it is understod as image (use the IVT).

Comment: Hello! Thank you! And yes, I was thinking of range as image – didn't know that it could also be used for a codomain. Thanks again!