# the cardinality of a domain of a function is larger than the cardinality of the range

Tags: analysis, functions

Is the cardinality of a domain of a function say f, must be larger than the cardinality of the range of f?

Say for sets A and B, we have a function mapping from A to B, does |A|>|B| be necessary?

Since according to Rudin,

> Consider two sets A and B, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever, and suppose that with each element x of A there is associated, in some manner, an element of B, which we denote by f(x). Then f is said to be a function from A to B (or a mapping of A into B). The set A is called the domain of f (we also say f is defined on A), and the elements f(x) are called the values of f The set of all values of f is called the range of f.

It didn't mention anything about the cardinality of both sets, but if we set A={1,2}, B={1,2,3}, we cannot get a function can we?

Comment: Obviously the cardinalities could be equal.

Comment: Are you claiming that there is no function from $\{1,2\}$ into $\{1,2,3\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confused the range of a function with its codomain.

In the explanation you quoted from Rudin, there is no reason to suspect that all elements of $B$ are used. So there is no reason $B$ can't be larger than $A$. For instance, with your example $A=\{1,2\},B=\{1,2,3\}$, there are many functions from $A$ to $B$, one of them being the mapping $f(1)=1, f(2)=2$. This way, $B$ is called the *codomain* of the function. There is in general no relation between the cardinalities of a domain and of a codomain.

However, one could also restrict $B$ to be just the elements that are hit by $f$. This is what's called the *range* of $f$, and it can indeed be no larger than $A$. (If you want to get technical, there are subtleties in that last sentence that involves the Axiom of Choice, but I think we can save that for later.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately notation is not standardized in the literature and this may lead to confusion.

If we have a function $f : A \to B$, then the only broad consensus is that $A$ is called the *domain of $f$*.

Some authors call $B$ the *codomain of $f$* (which I do prefer), other authors call it the *range of $f$*. What's more, some authors call the set $f(A) = \{ f(a) \mid a \in A \}$ the *image of $f$*  (which I do prefer), other authors (as Rudin) call it the *range of $f$*. The latter notation can of course only be used if $B$ wasn't named *range* before. Note that Rudin does not introduce *any name* for $B$.

See also [Is continuity impossible if a function range is a finite union of closed, bounded, disjoint sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4304148)

A similar notational issue occurs in Spivak's " Calculus". See my answer to  [Misleading Definitions and Unanswerable Problems in Spivak's Calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3790342).